# Local sql database and heroku postgres database files differ, how to sync again? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am currently doing the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. Somewhere along the way I messed up my database. In my database file there is only 1 user, by the name of Bob.

Locally in cloud9 IDE, when I do 'rails console' and then do Users.first, I get a user with a name of "Bob".

However when I do 'heroku rails run console' and do Users.first, I get a user with a different name. (I probably changed the name somewhere along the way)

How do I get Heroku to see the correct local database file again? Should I clear the heroku database, then use pg:pull to pull the local sql database to heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've gotten to Chapter 9 yet but [section 9.3.2](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-sample_users) of the current book deals with creating sample users. This is done through the `db/seeds.rb` file.

Running `$ bundle exec rake db:reset` then resets your DB followed by `$ bundle exec rake db:seed` to fill it with your new data.

You can run the same procedure on your production application with:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

It is, of course, also possible to transfer data between local and production databases with tools such as [heroku-pg-transfer](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer) but that's a little advanced if you're only starting out, and I think somewhat unnecessary if you only have one user to transfer over.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! All of my confusion came from the fact that I thought deploying my app also deploys the data.

Comment: No problem Christian. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [yaml_db gem](https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db) to dump your local data to file and then upload it to heroku.

On your development machine:

```
rake db:data:dump
```

Then commit changes, push to heroku and run:

```
heroku run rake db:data:load
```

Comment: Thank you. Will report back with results.